# Is Unity's scene manager such a thing that it deserve its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see we have the tag [scenemanager](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scenemanager).

100% of the occurrences are used with [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity).

Is it so special that it should have a tag of its own, or is it considered meta and should be made a synonym of Unity or blacklisted? After all, we have done something like that for [unity-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor) and [inspector](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspector) . We also did something like that for [unreal-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal-editor) .

Comment: Should not be a tag of its own, in my opinion.

Comment: @Almo that's a nice candidate for an answer :p

Comment: Nuke it. We already have a [scene] tag (whiiich itself lacks a description and wiki), which covers the more general case idea (Flash also had a concept of "scenes" you could switch between, as did Director (that thing that wasn't Flash but which was basically Flash and sometimes called Shockwave)).

Comment: @Draco18s This comment is also a good candidate for an answer :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I'm still sort of wary in the meta-space, posted. :)

Answer (score 4):

Nuke it.

We already have a [scene](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene) tag (which itself lacks a description and wiki), but it covers the more general idea as both Flash and [Shockwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Shockwave) have a concept of "scenes" you can switch between programmatically. Management of scenes on the different platforms is handled differently, but that's what platform tags are for. [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity)[scene](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene) vs. [flash](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash)[scene](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene).

Comment: Thus seems logical, though a note should be left in the "scene" tag to let other users know to also tag the engine they are using.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 The tag needs a description regardless, but yes, that is a good suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the most beneficial use of tags is to let the askers categorize their questions, so the answerers can navigate the site easier to find questions that interest them.

Purging all small tags will most probably result in having *god-tags*. They will become bloated and broad. This will eventually make people hold back from subscribing to them.

If [scenemanager](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scenemanager) is removed, then probably [scene](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene) tag will host these questions, but the tag [scene](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scene) also hosts the questions that are about, for example, *scene design*. But if a person wants to answer questions about *scene management* and not *scene design*, they will have to dig through a list of questions.

This is no good for answer writers. If the concept of tags loses its use for navigating the site, then I believe it is of no use besides moderation.

Also, considering the latest trend in the community, I say someone *can* be an expert in scene managers; but this one is just my opinion, not an industry observation.

Comment: Your argument seems to be that scene is already used too much, which isnt really something were automatically against. In this case, if you *really* wanted to look for these questions, you would look for questions tagged *scene* and *unity*.

Comment: @Gnemlock Actually no, my argument doesn't speak about present time. This may not become an immediate problem, but it will emerge over time as more and more questions get posted. I carefully constructed my sentences using future tense to reflect that. Regarding looking for both _unity_ and _scene_ tags, that doesn't ensure one will get only _unity scene **management**_ questions as the search result, they may also get questions about _unity scene **design**_.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin You should downvote Draco18s' answer :P